# reverse load on dc motor( series/shunt) and its speed control

Tags: motor, dc

if dc motor produces 10 Nm torque , and load acting on dc motor in reverse direction produces 6 Nm , then net torque is 10-6= 4Nm,
dc motor consumes current corresponding to 4Nm , and so speed becomes constant @4Nm,

my question in this case , how speed of dc motor to be increased ? without changing NET TORQUE .

Answer (score 1):

If a motor (that incidentally can produce a torque up to 10 N.m) is unloaded it will draw a smaller current than when it is loaded. Loading it with 6  N.m does not mean there is a net torque of 4 N.m. The torque seen by the motor is the torque required by the load.

If the speed drops to 50% when a loading torque of 5 N.m is applied then increasing the voltage will restore the speed but of course the torque generated will rise higher than 5 N.m.

You can't have one without the other; You can't simultaneously increase speed whilst maintaining torque constant unless the load itself has features that are partially equivalent to a constant power sink.

Power produced is \$2\pi n T\$ where n is revs per second and T is torque.

Comment: http://overvoltage.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/power_torque.gif

take a look at this graph, this synthesise what has been said by @Andy aka